# PayPal Referral Exclusions Now Shown as Direct/none

Tags: paypal, google-analytics, referrals

Like many others, we were frustrated by PayPal's lack of passing traffic source origination and getting all the conversion credit.

However, after adding PP to the referral exclusions list, now all we have is 100% of the conversions coming from direct/none. (We use PP as the exclusive checkout method)

So now while we have traffic that looks clean, the goal completion data is rendered useless as everything is direct/none.

Has anyone found a solution, other than switching to PayPal Pro?

Answer (score 0):

This problem could not be solved by any PayPal configuration.  User sessions are being broken before users get to PayPal.  Since you're seeing direct traffic and not self-referrals, that means not only is the session being broken, but user continuity.   Somewhere in a session on your site they're getting tracked as a new user (thus also inflating your user count).

My guess is that users arrive to the site on HTTP and then switch over to HTTPS (or switch to another domain) for the checkout process.  To solve this, you can setup [cross domain tracking](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034342?hl=en) (which is necessary even if using a single domain if the site is available on both HTTP and HTTPS).  An even better option (but possibly a greater lift) would be to move the entire site to HTTPS.